# Hide dropdown list options based on an entered value in a text box?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I will try and explain my situation as best as I can with the information I have. The short of it is that based on the value in the text box, I need to hide options in a dropdown list.

I have a text box with a building limit. It has an ID and then a location number as there are multiple buildings on the same page:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <label>Limit</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Building.Limit, htmlAttributes: new { id = "buildingLimit-" + Model.LocationNum })
    </div>
```

Below this I have a dropdown list with the a different ID but with the same location number:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <label>Occurrence</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Earthquake.Occurrence, new SelectList(Model.Earthquake.AggregateList, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "EarthquakeOcc-" + Model.LocationNum })
    </div>
```

Right now, that dropdown list is not at all tied to the buildingLimit. It displays several different values which can be selected. What I would like to do is if the buildingLimit is say $250,000 then the dropdown list should not have values greater than that. If they change it again to $1,000,000 then the dropdown list needs to adjust to have values no greater than $1,000,000

I have really been struggling on this one now. It sounds simple enough but I can't figure out how to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $("[id^='buildingLimit-']").change(function () {
    var location = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    var buildingLimit = $(this).val();

    var occArray = [];
    $("[id^='EarthquakeOcc-']").each(function (i, selected) {
        occArray[i] = $(selected).val();
        alert(occAccary[i]);
        if (occArray[i] > buildingLimit) {
            $("[id^='EarthquakeOcc'] option[value = occArray[i]").remove();
        }
    });
```

I know that there are several things wrong with it: it only works when the text box is changed and it just removes. Does not add back through .append(). Also, the values are hard coded:

```
public List<SelectListItem> AggregateList
    {
        get
        {
            if (aggregateList == null)
            {
                aggregateList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$100,000", Value = "100000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$250,000", Value = "250000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$500,000", Value = "500000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$1,000,000", Value = "1000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$2,000,000", Value = "2000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$3,000,000", Value = "3000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$4,000,000", Value = "4000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$5,000,000", Value = "5000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$6,000,000", Value = "6000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$7,000,000", Value = "7000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$8,000,000", Value = "8000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$9,000,000", Value = "8000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$10,000,000", Value = "10000000" });
                aggregateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "$25,000,000", Value = "25000000" });
            }
            return aggregateList;
        }
        set { aggregateList = value; }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your numbers are stored as strings.  So you should probably use parseInt() to force it to to do numeric comparisons instead of text comparisons.  Aside from that, could you explain what's not working?

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure how to hide certain values in the dropdown list based on buildingLimit criteria. I know there is .hide() in Jquery but that isn't supported in IE 8 which I need to support? I admit I am very new to this and have tried to figure it out for some time.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you're going to need an immutable list of all possible values. Trying to remove and recreate options, while also keeping everything ordered properly and such is an unnecessary pain. If you have a list of possible values, you can simply pull from that list, up to the defined threshold, based on the text box entry, to recreate the entire list of options. I would also recommend using a nice little JS library called [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/). It's not a strict requirement to make this work, but it makes converting back and forth between formatted currency string values and actual numeric values a ton easier.

Basically, you just need a list of the values in JS:

```js
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.AggregateList = [
    100000,
    250000,
    500000,
    ...
];
```

If you would prefer to create this list in your MVC view model and pass it to the view you can use something like the following instead:

```js
MyNamespace.AggregateList = @Json.Encode(Model.AggregateListValues);
```

Where `AggregateListValues` would be a `List<int>`, or similar.

Next, the way you're selecting the building limit and earthquake occurrence fields is highly inefficient. It's better  to put each pair of fields inside a wrapper such that you can select the other based on its proximity:

```html
<div class="location">
    <input id="buildingLimit" />
    <select id="EarthquakeOcc"> ... </select>
</div>
```

That code is intentionally simplified to illustrate what's happening; you're still free to use whatever other HTML you currently have wrapping those fields. Just make sure that both are grouped together within one parent. Then:

```js
    $('[id^=buildingLimit]').on('change', function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.location');
        var select = $('[id^=EarthquakeOcc]', parent);
    });
```

Also, for what it's worth, this frees you up to use the original ids, without having to manually specify the id, or and probably better, you could add a class to the fields instead, such that you can select them based on that class rather than their id attributes starting with a certain string, which would be a much cheaper selector for jQuery to process. (When you select by attribute, your selector is actually `*[attribute=value]`. In other words, jQuery must select every element in the DOM and then filter out the ones that don't have matching id values. Using a selector like `input[attribute=value]` would be better, as that narrows the field down to just input elements before jQuery much search each one. However, classes will always be faster, as jQuery can just rely on the native `document.getElementsByClassName`.)

For your event handler:

```js
$('[id^=buildingLimit]').on('change', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.location');
    var select = $('[id^=EarthquakeOcc]', parent);

    // if you choose not to use accounting.js, you just need to ensure that the value
    // gets turned into a number, using a combination of something like `replace` with
    // a regex and `parseInt`, etc.
    var limit = accounting.unformat($(this).val());

    var output = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (MyNamespace.AggregateList[i] <= limit) {
        // If you choose not to use accounting.js, you just need to implement your
        // own logic for formatting the number as you want
        output.push('<option value="' + MyNamespace.AggregateList[i] + '">$' + accounting.formatNumber(MyNamespace.AggregateList[i]) + '</option>');
        i++;
    }
    select.html(output.join(''));
});
```